# Bearer token cache using redis in .net 8

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, redis

I have Bearer token builder, which builds bearer token provider depending on my environment, in dev environment i'm using in memory cache for bearer tokens, but in production i want to use redis to cache bearer tokens.
Here is example of my bearer provider:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Redis cached bearer token provider.
/// </summary>
internal class RedisCachedBearerTokenProvider : IBearerTokenProvider
{
    private readonly string _scope;
    private readonly IConfidentialClientApplication _authApp;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="RedisCachedBearerTokenProvider"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="clientId">Client id.</param>
    /// <param name="clinetSecret">Client secret.</param>
    /// <param name="tenantId">Tenant id.</param>
    /// <param name="scope">Scope.</param>
    public RedisCachedBearerTokenProvider(
        string clientId,
        string clinetSecret,
        string tenantId,
        string scope)
    {
        _scope = Guard.Against.NullOrWhiteSpace(scope);
        var cId = Guard.Against.NullOrWhiteSpace(clientId);
        var cSecret = Guard.Against.NullOrWhiteSpace(clinetSecret);
        var tId = Guard.Against.NullOrWhiteSpace(tenantId);

        _authApp = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(cId)
            .WithTenantId(tId)
            .WithClientSecret(cSecret)
            .Build();
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public IConfidentialClientApplication Application => _authApp;

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public async Task<string> GetTokenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
     =>
        (await _authApp.AcquireTokenForClient(new[] { _scope }).ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken)).AccessToken;
}
```

Now i get stuck, how to add the redis cache for my token provider.

To add my provider to DI i've created a helper method which looks like:

```cs
public static IServiceCollection AddBearerTokenProviderService(
        this IServiceCollection services,
        Action<IBearerTokenProviderBuilder> providerConfig)
    {
        var builder = new BearerTokenProviderBuilder();
        providerConfig(builder);
        var provider = builder.Build();
        services.AddSingleton(provider);
        return services;
    }
```

in my Program.cs file I call my helper service like this:

```cs
services.AddBearerTokenProviderService(
            builder =>
            {
                var configValues = config.GetSection("BearerTokenProvider").Get<BearerTokenProviderOptions>();
                Guard.Against.Null(configValues);

                builder.WithClientId(configValues.ClientId)
                    .WithClientSecret(configValues.ClientSecret)
                    .WithTenantId(configValues.TenantId)
                    .WithScope(configValues.Scope)
                    .UseRedisCache();
            });
```

and also I have added redis in my program.cs file:

```
services.AddDistributedTokenCaches();
services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(act =>
{
    act.Configuration = "localhost:6379";
    act.InstanceName = "sampleInstance";
});
```

But it seems that my application ignores the redis, because I don't have any redis instance up, so basically there should be an connection exception.

Maybe some of you faced the similar problem? How to use two different cahching mechanism depending of env?

If you need additional info i can provide it to you.